# symfony twig variables in form field

Tags: symfony, variables, twig

I have a number of fields in my FromType file that have name :

```
//formType.php
for($i=0;$i<N;$i++){
 ->add('matricola_'.$i, TextType::class, array(
/*....*/
 ->add('tipologia_'.$i, TextType::class, array(
/*....*/
 ->add('esame_'.$i, TextType::class, array(
/*....*/
}
```

I don't understand in twig file how i can write this fields in a for cicle

I try differente way but without any result.

```
    //twig file
   {% for i in 0..10%}
             <tr>
                error <td>{{ form_widget(form.matricola_{{i}}) }}</td>
                error  <td>{{ form_widget(form.tipologia_{%i%}) }}</td>
                error  <td>{{ form_widget(form.esame_.i) }}</td>
            </tr>   
   {% endfor %}
```

Please help me and sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
{{ form_widget(form['matricola_' ~ i]) }}
```